# Delete in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

I am making a project and I have some problems.
I got a Flight class like this :

```
public class Flight implements Cloneable { 
   private String idFlight;
   private Horaire hourFlight;
   private String city;
   private static Vector<Flight> flights = new Vector<Flight>();
   private Hashtable<Integer,Task> tasks = new Hashtable<Integer,Task>();
   private Plane thePlane;
   ...
```

and I have a static method "cancelFlight" like this :

```
public static void cancelFlight(String idFlight){
    Flight v=getFlight(idFlight);
    Iterator<Task> it = v.tasks.values().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext)
    {
       it.remove();
    }
    int index=flights.indexOf(v);
    flights.remove(index);
```

But the tasks are also in a Hashtable of another class, Worker.

```
 private Hashtable<Integer,Task> tasks = new Hashtable <Integer,Task>();
```

So, what can I do ? Is there a method which is able to delete a instance of a class ?
An other solution that I have is to create a method into the class Worker "removeFromTask(int idTask)" but it's so complicated ... :(

Comment: Removing an object from one hashtable will not remove it from others.

Comment: Why do you keep the task hashtable is 2 places (Flight,Worker)? You need a better design.

Comment: No way should Worker have a hashtable of tasks.  First step in refactoring this is give this Worker class a Flight rather than trying to manage its own hashtable of tasks.  Then, when a task is removed from the flight, it will be updated for the Worker class.

Comment: @sergiu Well i have an Hashtable both in Worker and in Flight because Workers have a planning of tasks and must work on different tasks of different Flights which generate different tasks which can't be made by a same worker

Comment: I think what they're trying to tell you is that a Worker should only have one task (at any given time), probably the same for Flight. These should both get their current task from, let's say a Factory, which is where you could store the one HashMap to rule them all. :) The way you're doing it now, you're likely to have a ton of cyclic references, where what you really want is probably a nice tree structure.

Comment: Well, for "DepartureFlights" (extends Flight), there could be an infinite numbers of tasks at the same time for the same flight. It depends on the number of passengers of a flight, and the number of tasks is "numbers of passengers" % 90 +1.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke - They should get their tasks from "Dispatcher" or "ControlTower".

Comment: @HotLicks Sure, which happens to use a Factory pattern. :)

Answer (score -1):

If tasks property is referenced in both classes, you don't need to do an additional remove operation there. But if you clone it (i.e creating new map instance), you need to remove the tasks in another class too.

Comment: To the extent that I can make any sense at all of what you said, it's wrong.

Comment: No you're wrong Hot Licks. As i told on my answer, if you remove some object from hashmap and you have a reference of this hashmap in another field it will be also removed there.

Try this : 

        Map<String, File> filesMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
        Map<String, File> referenced = filesMap;

        filesMap.put("something", new File("/dev/null"));
        filesMap.remove("something");

        System.out.println(filesMap);
        System.out.println(referenced);

You will see that after removing something from filesMap effects also referenced map!

Comment: That's not the OP's question. He has 2 data structures, and yes he will need to remove them from both.